# UE4 crashes because of the simple rotation script

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I've made a simple script just like in the video tutorial. It compiles without errors and when I press Play button, the engine crashes. Why is this happening?

[image]

.h

```
#pragma once
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
#include "MyActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class ROTATION_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    AMyActor();

protected:
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "MyActor.h"

AMyActor::AMyActor()
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

}

void AMyActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    FString a = GetOwner()->GetName(); // ERROR
}

void AMyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Without knowing Unreal at all: `GetOwner()->GetName()` smells like nullptr. Does `GetOwner()` return `nullptr` in some cases?

Comment: @user2328447 I guess yes, but don't know why. It shouldnt't be null and it woks in the video tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the crash, you should be checking for a nullptr.

```
auto Owner = this->GetOwner();
if (Owner)
{
  //use Owner
}
```

That will at least let you print some logs to trace the issue. The issue itself is likely because your AActor derived class has no owner (as in it is not a component of another class). If you are trying to get the name of `this` AActor, you can just call `this->GetName()`.